# Python regex substitution using a dictionary

Tags: python, regex, dictionary

I have the following regex to parse access strings inside brackets and remove them:

```
>>> a = 'a[b]cdef[g ]hi[ j]klmno[ p ]'
>>> re.sub(r'\[\s?(.*?)\s?\]',r'\1',a)
'abcdefghijklmnop'
```

But what I want to do is have what is in brackets target a dictionary. Let's say I have the following dictionary:

```
d = {'b':2,'g':7,'j':10,'p':16}
```

when I run my desired regex it should print the string: `'a2cdef7hi10klmno16'`

However, I cannot simply have the replace part of `sub` be `d['\1']` because there will be a `KeyError: '\x01'`.

**Is there any simple way to replace a pattern with a dictionary responding to a capture in regex?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`format`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format), assuming `a` doesn't contain substrings of the form `{...}`:

```
>>> import re
>>> a = 'a[b]cdef[g ]hi[ j]klmno[ p ]'
>>> d = {'b':2,'g':7,'j':10,'p':16}
>>> 
>>> re.sub(r'\[\s?(.*?)\s?\]',r'{\1}',a).format(**d)
'a2cdef7hi10klmno16'
```

Or you can use a `lambda`:

```
>>> re.sub(r'\[\s?(.*?)\s?\]', lambda m: str(d[m.group(1)]), a)
'a2cdef7hi10klmno16'
```

---

The `lambda` solution appears to be much faster:

```
>>> from timeit import timeit
>>>
>>> setup = """
... import re
... a = 'a[b]cdef[g ]hi[ j]klmno[ p ]'
... d = {'b':2,'g':7,'j':10,'p':16}
... """
>>>
>>> timeit(r"re.sub(r'\[\s?(.*?)\s?\]',r'{\1}',a).format(**d)", setup)
13.796708106994629
>>> timeit(r"re.sub(r'\[\s?(.*?)\s?\]', lambda m: str(d[m.group(1)]), a)", setup)
6.593755006790161
```

Comment: is there any difference in performance or a reason to use one over the other

Comment: @RyanSaxe I think the lambda solution will be faster, and it seems better suited for this situation.

Answer (score 0):

```
newstring = [(d[i] if i in d else i) for i in string]
re.sub(r'\[\s?(.*?)\s?\]',r'\1',a)
```

This should do what you want by first substituting the characters, then removing the brackets, assuming the values of the dictionary are also strings. If not, simply replace d[i] with str(d[i]).

Answer (score 0):

The Python regex replace function can take arbitrary replacement functions to replace with:

```
import re
d = {'b': 2, 'g': 7, 'j': 10, 'p': 16} 
def repl_fn(matchobj):
  return str(d[matchobj.group(0)])
regex = re.compile('[' + ''.join(d.iterkeys()) + ']')
print regex.sub(repl_fn, 'abcdefghijklmnop')
```

Answer (score 0):

with regex im not sure. But you can just do this.

```
a = 'a[b]cdef[g ]hi[ j]klmno[ p ]'
result = re.sub(r'\[\s?(.*?)\s?\]',r'\1',a)
newresult = result
for char in result:
  value = d.get(char)
  if value:
    newresult = re.sub(char, value, newresult)
print newresult
```